# Data tables & JQuery Broken in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

I have written a wordpress plugin that uses Jquery to confirm all the form's information has been filled in, and it also makes use of Datatables to display the information.

Though it works perfectly in Chrome and newer versions of IE, it does not work in IE8. The Jquery does not seem to throw errors, but there are a few errors in the console...

Is there some way to get around this? or does IE8 just not work with JQuery?
I assume if we get the datatables function to work, the other should work too?

**The Code**

```
$('.datatables').DataTable({
        'lengthMenu': [[10, 50, 100, 500, -1], [10, 50, 100, 500, "All"]],
        'info': false,
        'searching': false
    });
```

**The error**
`Object doesn't support this property or method`

Where can I start looking or working to get around this problem?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: This is incomplete code, so there's not enough information to answer.  Is that script in a document ready? How is jQuery loaded in your plugin?  Which line throws the `object doesn't support this property or method` error?

Answer (score 0):

The datatables author suggests omitting the `pdfmake` plugin for his control. See this: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/30385/datatables-or-a-plugin-1-10-9-ie8-compatibility